# What is the meaning of "followed by" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> On week two of her long, slow campaign for recovery, one of the
> students met Kathleen. He listened to her heart murmur, and he and I
> talked about aortic stenosis, and its association with blackouts and
> the risk of sudden death. We discussed what might be done about it –
> an echocardiogram back in the big hospital to assess its severity,
> **followed by** a decision: open surgery versus the newer, less invasive
> transcatheter aortic valve implantation, both performed in the
> regional cardiothoracic centre sixty miles down the road.

This is from Lucy Pollock's *[The Book About Getting Older](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=0LHSDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&lpg=PT49&dq=%22an%20echocardiogram%20back%20in%20the%20big%20hospital%22&source=bl&ots=TDLSdhM0D8&sig=ACfU3U3vVNh2EAH1_4xzM-HXRhqP36W0SQ&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjomM2qo_nxAhXWEogKHeqzDqQQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22an%20echocardiogram%20back%20in%20the%20big%20hospital%22&f=false)*.
I'm having trouble interpreting the last sentence because of "followed by".
Can I understand the story as "the decision of whether to get open surgery or less invasive transcatheter aortic valve implantation in the regional cardiothoracic centre sixty miles down the road will "be based on" an echocardiogram back in the big hospital to assess its severity."?

Comment: Why do you think that there could be  more than one way to understand the 'story'? *Followed by* here means what it always means; the question doesn't present any problem concerning English language and usage that would be within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is that once the echocardiogram is done, it will be obvious ***which of the two options*** will be best: ***open surgery*** OR ***the newer, less invasive transcatheter aortic valve implantation***. So the assessment performed by the echocardiogram will be ***[followed by](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/followed_by/synonyms)*** decision-making - a choice between these two options, which have something in common: they are *both performed in the regional cardiothoracic centre sixty miles down the road.*